# jenkins - parallel branch name is not fully seen

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli, jenkins-blueocean

I got massive parallel job with multiple stages and branches. Using this pipe structure:

```
def build_jobs = [:]

build_jobs['BUILD PROGRAMM1'] = {
    node('node1'){
        stage('Clean WS'){
        }
        stage('GIT'){
        }
        stage('Build'){
        }
    }
}
build_jobs['BUILD PROGRAMM2'] = {
    node('node1'){
        stage('Clean WS'){
        }
        stage('GIT'){
        }
        stage('Build'){
        }
    }
}

build_jobs['Basic Checks'] = {
    node('node1'){
        stage('Clean WS'){
        }
        stage('GIT'){
        }
        stage('Build'){
        }
    }
}
parallel build_jobs
```

The branch name of parallel branches is not seen.

[image]

Is it possible to change the branch name location to make it fully seen ? Above the hole branch flow ?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to instead run three sequential nodes ("Clean WS", "GIT", "Build") each having  lots of parallel stages with branch name? It would be certainly seen better.

Comment: Currently it really helps to monitor failure, so trying to solve it without changing the pipe architecture.

Comment: You may try adding a dummy stage  `stage("BUILD PROGRAMM1") {} ` before `CLEAN` stage.

Comment: @MaratC This is not a preferred option